# Why can't we use closed sets to make covers for compactness?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

In particular, what about the real line? If our topology is generated by sets of the form [a,b] or [a,b), why can't we form an open cover of, say, [0,1] with those and be guaranteed a finite subcover?

I'm sure it's a simple counterexample. I don't know how it's escaping me...

Comment: It is **absolutely essential** that for each point $x\in X$ a neighborhood of $x$ is present in the cover. When all sets of the cover are open this condition is automatically satisfied. If some or all sets of the cover are closed, e.g., consist of only one point, it is possible that you cannot do with a finite number of them.

Answer (score 5):

If the topology is generated by "open" sets of the form $[a,b]$, then singletons are also "open": $$[b-1,b]\cap[b,b+1] = \{b\}.$$ Hence, only finite sets can be compact in this topology.

The case $[a,b)$ is somewhat different: infite union of "open" sets has to be "open", hence we build an "open" set $$\bigcup_{n\ge 1}[a+1/n,a+2) = (a,a+2).$$ This allows us to conclude that this topology is finer than the usual one and therefore it has fewer compact sets. For example, the "open" cover of $[0,1]$ can be given by this model: let the sequence $a_n$ satisfy $$0=a_1,\quad \forall n\, a_n<a_{n+1},\quad \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = 1.$$
We cover $[0,1]$ by "open" intervals $[a_n,a_{n+1})$, $n\in\Bbb N$ and one more interval $[1,2)$. Obviously, this cover has no finite subcovers, therefore $[0,1]$ is not a compact set in this topology.

One of problems in your approach that you should be able to find a finite subcover from *any* open cover, not just from a well-tailored cover.

Comment: You inverted "compact" and "finite" in your last statement.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro, actually, no, it was just a bad grammar structure. I'll rephrase that sentence. Thanks for the catch, though=)

Comment: Right, I realized that I needed to do it for any open cover - I was trying to think through all the different possibilities and had missed that one. I'm sorry, but I'm still missing the similar case - I'm having trouble constructing an open singleton.

Comment: @BGreen see edits.